# filter by array size in kibana discover

Tags: lucene, kibana

I am trying to write a Lucene query in kibana's discover which returns only documents that the array size of certain key are bigger than a value

Meaning I want all documents that their length of the value array of a specific value is bigger than a given number

Answer (score 0):

there's no way to do this with a lucene query. you'd need to create a painless scripted/runtime field to count the array items, then query that with kql